# How can I use a join to combine these two queries?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: articles and modifications.  I want users to easily be able to revert their article back to it's original state if they realize they shouldn't have modified it.  Instead of using an extra query to find the id of the article's newest modification, I would like to use a join.  So I want to get the information from the articles table and then join the modifications table to it to return the associated row.  This is what I have now:

```
<?php

$query = "
     SELECT
          article_id, title, content
     FROM articles
     WHERE article_id = ".$article_id."
     LIMIT 1";

$query_article = $this->db->query($query);
$article = $query_article->row_array();

$query_mod = "
    SELECT
         modification_id, article_id, title, content, date
     FROM modifications
     WHERE article_id = ".$article_id."
     ORDER BY modification_id DESC
     LIMIT 1";

$query_mod = $this->db->query($query);
if($query_mod->num_rows() > 0){
     $mod = $query_mod->row_array();
     $article_title = $mod['title'];
     $article_content = $mod['content'];
} else {
     $article_title = $article['title'];
     $article_content = $article['content'];
}
```

How could I combine these two queries into one using a join?

```
SELECT
   a.title, a.content, a.article_id
   m.modification_id AS mod_id, m.title AS mod_title, m.content AS mod_content
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN modifications AS m ON (...)
WHERE a.article_id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If your question is about MySQL, why is all of the PHP code here? The only relevant parts are the two SQL statements.

Comment: I'm just showing an example of how i execute it so you can see what I'm doing.  Does it matter?  Not really.

Comment: It adds unnecessary, irrelevant clutter to the question, and makes it harder to read. It also makes it more difficult to answer, because the answer is an SQL statement, and to test that statement you have to strip out all of the irrelevant PHP code. So yes, it matters.

Comment: And it's definitely relevant.  Some people may not understand the question by reading my text(as apposed to code).  Including the PHP code is meant to help them understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: There's no need for rude behavior here. In fact, it's expressly forbidden by the rules of conduct - you can read them in the [help] if you're not familiar. You should want to make things as easy as possible for the people you're asking for free help to solve **your problem"*, and it's usually a good idea to avoid being rude to them. Learn to accept constructive criticism and be polite.

Comment: If people really don't like that I've included the PHP code, they can vote my question down.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 It isn't difficult to distinguish, that is true. But a good SQL question explains the structure of the involved tables, explains their relationship, and offers a sample of what the query's desired output should be. You're requiring us to reverse-engineer all those components from the PHP code.

Comment: So moving past the arguments - do you know much about how joins work? Do you want to return a row for `articles` even if it has no associated row in `modifications`?

Comment: I know about using basic joins... In other words, simple ON clauses that get rows from another table based on the original table's auto increment id.  I don't really know how to use subqueries in a join. And yes, I would like to return the article row without any regard to whether or not there is a modification row associated with the article row.

Comment: Is it possible that there are more than one row in `modifications` per `article_id`? If so, how do you choose which one to return in `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Oh yes, it is quite possible.  There could be 100 modifications for any given article.  The mod returned is based on the most recent one(e.g. ORDER BY mod_id DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: Of course, sorry I didn't notice the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your skeletal attempt at a query is pretty much correct except for the empty `ON` clause, which merely needs to identify equality between `article_id` on the two tables. It is correct to use a `LEFT JOIN` since you need to return the article regardless of a match in `modifications`.

```
SELECT
   a.title, a.content, a.article_id,
   m.modification_id AS mod_id, m.title AS mod_title, m.content AS mod_content
FROM 
   articles AS a
   LEFT JOIN modifications AS m ON a.article_id = m.article_id
WHERE a.article_id = 1
ORDER BY mod_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

However, your PHP logic shows that you are conditionally using the `title,content` from the `modifications` table if it is present. For that, you may use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) directly in the SQL to return the first non-null argument, so if the `LEFT JOIN` has no match, `article` will be used.

```
SELECT
   -- COALESCE to prefer the modifications value if non-null
   COALESCE(m.title,a.title) AS title,
   COALESCE(m.content, a.content) AS content,
   a.article_id,
   m.modification_id AS mod_id
FROM 
   articles AS a
   LEFT JOIN modifications AS m ON a.article_id = m.article_id
WHERE a.article_id = 1
ORDER BY mod_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Here's a demonstration**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1085c/1

Because you're only attempting to return details for one `article_id`, no subqueries are needed. This gets a little more complicated if you want to return the latest for multiple `article_id`, requiring a subquery join with a `MAX()` aggregate.

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(m.title,a.title) AS title,
   COALESCE(m.content, a.content) AS content,
   a.article_id,
   m.modification_id AS mod_id
FROM 
   articles AS a
   -- Join articles against a subquery to get the most recent mod_id only
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT article_id, MAX(modification_id) AS mod_id
     FROM modifications
     GROUP BY article_id
   ) mm ON mm.article_id = a.article_id
   -- and then join that mod_id against the rest of the modifications table
   LEFT JOIN modifications m ON mm.mod_id = m.modification_id
WHERE article_id IN (<multiple criteria for article_id>)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14051/2

Comment: The final query you provided may have been more complicated as far as SQL goes, but it cut down the overall length of my code.  Now I don't have to use a condition to replace the title and content.  Thanks a bunch!